# Google Maps sample code not running in localhost

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am not sure as what is reason for this.I copied the sample code and trying to run it in dreamweaver on localhost.But for some reasons I dont see map getting loaded.I remember earlier it used to load it but now its not loading.I have valid api keys and my site is still not public.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
     <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var geocoder;
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
      }

      function codeAddress() {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
  <!--  <div>
      <input id="address" type="textbox" value="myaddress">
      <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
    </div>-->
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:90%;top:30px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is simplest code but still I am not able to get it up.

```
enter code here
```

Key Value
Request GET /maps/api/js/QuotaService.RecordEvent?1shttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fgeoc.html&4e1&5e0&6u1&7sc7c7sc&callback=*xdc*._papnzo&token=120226 HTTP/1.1

Can someone take a look and suggest me as how to get this up ? I have to geocode the address and then pass it to places api.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?  Is the map not showing?  What is that "Key Value Request" that you posted?

Comment: key value details are from f12 tools of browser,wanted to check if there is anything related to quota blocking my call.I think this is not the case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set a size for your map, this works for me:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:500px;width:600px;"></div>
```

or this CSS:

```
body, html, #map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_geocoderExample.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
body,
html,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="address" type="textbox" value="126 Beacon Avenue Jersey City NJ 07306 USA">
  <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
</div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Yup geocodezip, I did not set the size correctly.One clarification,does maps dont take percentage values  or we need to give explicity values in pixels ?

Comment: You can use percentage sizing. But you need to make sure the size of the parent element is defined or it doesn't work... [Using a percentage height for the map div](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm)

Comment: Thanks Geocodezip. I will check the link also.Works now perfectly.